# form processing with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Is there any way to completely process a form using only javascript & html ? 
I need to process a form for a school project but using only JS & HTML  with no use of cgi scripts, php,…
I don’t want anyone to actually make my homework for me, just a pointer in the right direction :)

edit: With processing the form i mean the onSubmit action, submit the info to the administrator either through mail, write it to a file, ...
I have already made a script to validate the inputs.

Comment: What do you mean by 'process'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form Processing which I am assuming at the very least will be adding the form data to database and validate ofcourse.

You can validate using jQuery[a js Library] [Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Also you can post form data using [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume by 'process' you mean validate. If you are allowed to use a library, use jQuery with its validation plugin

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Otherwise

```
var inputs, index, form;

form = document.getElementById('myFormId'); // or form = document.formName
inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
    // deal with inputs[index] element.
}
```

I hope those can get you started

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any ways to use *client-side* JavaScript which don't have so many or such serious caveats (such as "IE only and with big security warnings" or "Only if certain email clients are installed") as to make them useless except under very specialised circumstances.

You can use server side JavaScript though. [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is the current popular choice for that.